# What are Python 3 guarantees on float type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, is it guaranteed that float in Python 3 is the 64-bit IEEE-754 binary floating-point type?

Comment: [Almost all machines today (November 2000) use IEEE-754 floating point arithmetic, and almost all platforms map Python floats to IEEE-754 “double precision”.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: @CoryKramer if today = November 2000, what day is it tomorrow? ;)

Comment: @Chris_Rands Uhh.... hopefully not [January 2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error) describe this in a passing mention:

> almost all platforms map Python floats to IEEE-754 “double
>   precision”.

So, no, it's not a language guarantee but it does seem like CPython will use it everywhere it's available.

[Rejected PEP 754](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0754/) describes in its rejection notice:

> Several ideas of this PEP were implemented for Python 2.6.
>   float('inf') and repr(float('inf')) are now guaranteed to work on
>   every supported platform with IEEE 754 semantics.